# What's the worst-case delay for BTC->USD?

Tags: exchanges

For big exchanges like mtgox, what is the longest delay time seen between ordering a sell and closing it?

In other words if I do an emergency sell of a large amount of coins because the exchange rate is dropping by the second, how much value might I lose while waiting for the sell order to complete?

Are there any exchanges that basically guarantee that the price in USD of my sell order when I place it will be the amount in USD I receive no matter how long their system takes to complete it?

Answer (score 1):

When the BTC funds are on your [MtGox](https://mtgox.com/) account, a market sell order is nearly instantaneous and so done in a few seconds, dependent on the amount you buy.

Depositing Bitcoins to MtGox requires [6 confirmations](https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20195237-General-Questions) before they show up in your account. 6 confirmations means 6 blocks to be mined since your transaction, this [will averagely take 1 hour](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Blocks#What_is_the_maximum_number_of_blocks.3F) to complete.

The time for withdrawing your US dollars will strongly depend on the [withdrawal method](https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20490576-Withdrawals-and-Deposits) you want to use.

Note that there are many other exchanges and so this answer only holds for MtGox. It's likely that other exchanges require less confirmations and/or have faster withdrawal methods.